# how to convert a string to a date format and then convert it back into a date in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to convert a string that is of format (`YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`) to date format(`DD-MON-RR`). After this I have to again convert it back to a string format(`MM/DD/YYYY`).

I have done this using the below Query

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('string to be converted','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY') 
FROM table_name
```

But I am getting an error like

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
>   01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
>   *Cause:    Illegal year entered
>   *Action:   Input year in the specified range

Can any one please suggest ideas for this.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Another good reason why you should never, ever store dates as strings.

Comment: Please provide a sample input you're using for the string.

Comment: The Sample input is '2014-03-18 00:00:00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your table values, because if they respected your format your query would be ok. For instance,

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('2014-03-12 15:19:33','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM dual
```

gives `03/12/2014`, as expected.

**EDIT :** I could not reproduce your error (was getting ORA-01861 instead), so I tried naively to run

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('string to be converted','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM dual
```

and I do get the same error ORA-01841 as yours: this is because you are trying to convert `'string to be converted'`, which is not respecting the format ! You should take an Oracle **field**, something like `table_name.date_field`.

Comment: If I am executing this Query alone i am able to get the answer. But if i am integrating into the main query, I am getting the above mentioned error

Comment: If I am executing this Query alone i am able to get the answer. But if i am integrating into the main query, I am getting the above mentioned error